# Overriding user agent stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet, user-agent

For some reason my website won't use my  styles!

I have this in my stylesheet:

```
#nav {
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 965px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 0px #f2e9e1 solid;
  height: 2.1em;
}

#nav ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  line-height: 17px;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 90
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.0px;
  line-height: 17px;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#nav ul li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1c140d;
   margin: 0;   
}
```

Part of my HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="level1">
            <li><a href="http://comparative-legumes.org/development_activities">Development</a></li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="no_cursor">Search</a>
                    <ul class="level2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; ">
                            <li><a href="http://search.comparative-legumes.org">Seqqle search by sequence</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://soybase.org:8085/cvits/new">CViT search tool</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://soybase.org:8085/gene_families">Leggle search</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
```

But my developer tools says that the matched CSS rules for the first <li> is li instead of #nav ul li.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you include your stylesheet?

Comment: Did you double-checked whether (via your developer tools) that the CSS-file is actually included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea, but make sure your stylesheet is actually being loaded.  Unless you've changed something in your browser, there is no reason those styles shouldn't be working.

Also, if you can, provide a URL we can look at.

Comment: not in production yet. When I change other parts of the same stylesheet it has an effect on the website.

Comment: Odd. Do you load any other stylesheets that contain selectors with a higher **[specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)** than the ones in your question above?  And, are the styles you mentioned above even displayed in your developer tools?  If not, look for any syntax errors in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML / CSS seems to be working as intended; I can see that [the | turns red when I add `color: red;` to the `#nav ul li` rule](http://jsfiddle.net/eLZnx/1/).  There must be something else (style sheet garbled or not loaded, other code) going on here.